# Unable to find image from docker hub repository

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am a really newbie in docker and basically I've started to follow this official guide:
https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

I've executed this commands:
step 1 --> docker pull mongo

step 2--> docker images 
and the output:
REPOSITORY                                                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mongo                                                             latest              3f3daf863757        2 weeks ago         388MB

step 3 --> docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo:tag

Unable to find image 'latest:tag' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for latest, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance,

Comment: In the `docker run` command, the `...:tag` needs to be one of the tags at the top of the Docker Hub page, or you can leave it off entirely (same meaning as `...:latest`).  `docker run` will pull the image for you if it needs to.

Comment: There is no image called `latest:tag` check again your command especially this part `-d mongo:tag`

Comment: thanks! now works with :
docker run --name my-mongodb  -d mongo:latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to run with below command. you are not passing the correct tag name. available list of tag for MongoDB are here. https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo?tab=tags

```
docker run --name my-mongodb  -d mongo:latest
```

Comment: @mononoke83 welcome. Can you please also vote for the answer.